# Share custom stories explicitly using share dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the Open Share Dialog from Facebook SDK for iOS in my iPhone App to share a custom story. I created open graph action and object which is already successfully approved by Facebook review team and live.

But if a user shares a story using my App, it's not shown on the news feed of his friends. So I googled a lot and looked here in stackoverflow and everyone writes to set the ExplicitlyShared flag to true. But this is not working for me using the share dialog. After setting this flag to true user stories will not be generated anymore and the post button is disabled.

Also in the Developer Docs Facebook provides this hint:
[image]

Anybody a solution?

I used exactly the same code as in the Facebook OpenGraph Share Dialog sample on GitHub: https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos/tree/master/FBOGSampleSD