# ios facebook custom story not showing in newsfeed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a custom story with a custom action and custom properties. All of this is approuved by Facebook. My action have the explicit share capacity whitch should post the graph action on the newsfeed.

When i test my code from my device with FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction, everything is fine, no errors, no logs. On Facebook i can see the post in my timeline and activity log but NOT in my newsfeed.

This problem exists only in Facebook desktop version. In my fb mobile app, the custom story appear in newsfeed, no issue in this case.

My facebook application is in sandbox mode.

I have search a lot on the web and see a few solutions like the explicit_shared flag on the action but not working.

Have somebody resolved this problem ?

Comment: Every custom action you add, should have similar object added as a custom story in your app dashboard

Comment: I'm also having similar issues. Facebook app is live and custom story added to dashboard and has been approved by FB. My iOS app doesn't implement FB login as it is not required if using the Share Dialog according to the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph/#sharedialog). On my Facebook mobile app, the app generated story appears in both my timeline as well as news feed (no issues there) BUT in the desktop version, it doesn't appear in both - only appears in the activity log where the post setting is set to 'Allowed on timeline'. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ken, i'm having the same issue than you : the problem is in the desktop version only.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue like you! Already posted here on Stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671007/share-custom-stories-explicitly-using-share-dialog) and a few times in the FB DevGroup, but no one could help me. First I thought that I have to set the flag "explicitly shared" true, but this not allowed, because posts with share dialog should be automatically explicit and visible in the news feed. I think it's a bug and FB doesn't care about it. Because I found no solution, I removed FB from my App. If you find a solution, please let me know! Thanks, Matthias

Comment: Reported a bug, maybe it'll help https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/593504357402622/